# CHECK for two columns

Tags: sql, database

I have a problem with my code.
As you can see i Try to have a sort of CHECK constraint using two columns in the same table but seems does not work.
My need is to accept value in EffectiveEndDate only if they are > that EffectiveStartDate.

Any idea how to solve it? thanks for your support! :-)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test 
(   
EffectiveStartDate  dateTime2(2)        NOT NULL,
EffectiveEndDate    dateTime2(2)        NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT CK_CmsSponsoredContents_EffectiveEndDate CHECK (EffectiveEndDate > EffectiveStartDate),
);
```

Comment: The constraint appears to be correct to me. What isn't working? Are you able to insert end dates that are before the start dates?

Comment: missing comma before 'constraint'?

Comment: same question from same author <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438066>

Comment: possible duplicate of [CHECK CONSTRAINT on multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438066/check-constraint-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a comma in the wrong spot:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(  
  EffectiveStartDate dateTime2(2) NOT NULL,
  EffectiveEndDate   dateTime2(2) NOT NULL,  -- added missing comma
  CONSTRAINT CK_CmsSponsoredContents_EffectiveEndDate CHECK (EffectiveEndDate>EffectiveStartDate)
)
```

Removed a comma at the end of the check constraint declaration.