# Check contraint for two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where there are two columns: RowType (INT) and RefId (INT).
The value of both columns are zero or more.

I need to check:

```
If RowType == 1 Then RefId cannot be = 0
```

What is the best way to do it ?

As I see I can check

```
CREATE TABLE (
  ...
  CONSTRAINT MyCheck CHECK (RowType + RefId <> 1)
```

to do it, but may be the is a more general way for such checkings ?

Comment: Useful link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438066/check-constraint-on-multiple-columns

Comment: How can I apply to my case ? I know how to use check constrain on the table level. My question about using `if-then` logic in the check constraint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_2cols
    check (rowtype <> 1 or refid <= 0);
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_2cols
    check (not (rowtype = 1 and refid > 0) );
```

Note:  There might be slight modifications if the columns can be `NULL`.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks.  Didn't know that it is possible to boolean expressions in CHECK's